# NAT for a local device on pfSense - what am I missing?

Tags: routing, lan, nat, pfsense, pf

I have an old and odd 1980s device (it's part of an early controller I've had for ages).

It has a hard-coded address of 192.168.1.100 and apparently (perhaps because of its age) it expects to have a subnet of 192.168.1.100/24 and actually won't respond to anything unless it's from that subnet. It's connected to the OPT1 NIC on my pfSense router, which has interface 192.168.1.1/24.

What I'd like to do is set up some kind of NAT rule or VIP in the router, that would allow my desktop to talk directly to it. My desktop IP is 192.168.3.2 and the LAN NIC has interface 192.168.3.1/24. For example either of these setups:

1. *Option 1* - Packets received on the LAN interface from source=192.168.3.2 dest=192.168.1.100 are forwarded on OPT1 as
   usual, but with the packet NATed to have source=192.168.1.1 (OPT1's
   IP) dest=192.168.1.100 - so the device "sees" them as coming from
   the required subnet. Its replies are then picked up by the router at
   OPT1 and forwarded on LAN back to 192.168.3.2
2. *Option 2* - Packets on the LAN interface which are sent to a virtual LAN IP dest=192.168.3.100 are accepted by the router which 'behind the
   scenes' forwards them on OPT1 with the packet modified to have
   source=192.168.1.1 (OPT1's IP) dest=192.168.1.100 - so the device
   "sees" them as coming from the required subnet. Its replies are then
   picked up by the router at OPT1 and forwarded on the LAN with the
   source 192.168.1.100 mapped back to 192.168.3.100, so when they are
   received by the desktop they appear to have come from a device on
   the LAN rather than outside it.

The difference between the two options is that in the first, the original packets are sent to the non-LAN IP and the router modifies their source when forwarding them on OPT1. In the second the original packets are sent to a virtual IP on the LAN instead, and the router modifies both their source and dest before forwarding them.

Both of these are pretty much identical to what pfSense does with virtual IPs and other NAT options, so I'm fairly sure this isn't hard to do.  But I can't seem to make either of these work - NAT is quite a complex area!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The solution is called Outbound NAT, which translates the *source IP* or the packet, not (as is more usual) the destination IP.

Unfortunately the documentation is a bit ambiguous and easily misunderstood on Outbound NAT, so this was the full answer I found:

I had assumed NAT would be applied to a packet that was outbound (ie entering the router via some interface), but it's actually applied to the packet as it's outbound *from* the router, on the outgoing interface.

1. I set up a virtual IP of type "IP alias" (but perhaps some other types would have worked just as well) with *the IP that I wanted the packet to look like it came from* (anything in the 192.168.1.0/24 range in this example - for example 192.168.1.5). The IP alias needs to be on an interface - I used the interface it would *leave* the router on (OPT1 in this example), not the one it arrives into the router at.
2. I enabled hybrid NAT (Manual/AON NAT would also have worked) and then added an Outbound NAT rule on the same interface (OPT1) with source = any (or whatever IP range the packet actually came from) and dest = the destination IP or its subnet or whatever (I used 192.168.1.0/24). Then I set the "translation address" by choosing the virtual IP I had entered in step 1, from the drop-down box.

This does what I want. The packet, sent to its destination IP, travels in from the LAN and is picked up by NAT when it's outgoing at OPT1 (the interface in the NAT rule). As the packet's src matches "any" and its dest matches the value entered in the NAT rule (192.168.1.0/24), its source is translated to be 192.168.1.5 as required, before being sent out through OPT1.

Packet capture confirms it - when I ping as described in the 1st post, packet capture on the OPT1 interface shows a ping and reply from 192.168.3.2 -> 192.168.1.100, but packet capture on the OPT2 interface shows a ping and reply from 192.168.1.5 -> 192.168.1.100 as desired.

This is useful not only for my device, but for any other situation where packets need to appear to come from the same subnet as another device.